# Executing a PHP script with a CRON Job

Tags: php, automation, cron

I would like to run a PHP script every day at midnight. After research on how to do this, it appears that the best way to achieve this is to use a CRON job.

If my php script was located at http://example.com/scripts/scriptExample.php, can somebody be able to show the most simple example of what this CRON command would look like?

I have looked through numerous posts but I cannot find a simple enough example for me to learn and build upon.

Comment: are you running this script on windows or linux ?

Comment: I believe the server is a linux one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron  `0 0 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/phpscript` 0min 0hour every day month year. php with full path on local server, php script with full path.  OR `0 0 * * * wget  http://example.com/scripts/scriptExample.php`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Crontab needs the full path on your server.

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/example.php
```

This will execute every day at midnight.

Comment: This is great. I will try this command out once the script has been finished. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This code is not working with me!

Comment: And because that the easy way it's requesting the "page" via wget or lynx in this way: http://hardforo.com/thread-460-post-1234.html

Comment: yeah this work for me

Answer (score 2):

So something like this:

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

The 00 * * * * means hourly 
/usr/local/bin/php - where php main engine is in
/home/john/myscript.php - the script to run (physical path)

You can use also @hourly special key:

```
@hourly /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

Answer (score 2):

If You have a sudo access to your linux server :-
Then do the following

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This will open the cron tab for you on your server.

Next thing is you have to do a cron entry for the file which you want to execute

```
00 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/php "path of the php file which you want to execute"
```

`00 00 * * *` this will run your cron at midnight daily, means at 0hrs and 0mins

Comment: As both are 0. Its 0 mins, 0 hours to be precise, the order is: MINS HOURS DAYOFMONTH MONTH DAYOFWEEK #command#

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a company to host your website?

As you should have a icon  in your `c panel` called `cron jobs` from there you can tell it what script to execute and when.

Comment: I am yes. That sounds promising Chris. I will take a look.

Comment: My cPanel does have this Chris which is great. However the actual command I need to provide is what I need help with now. An example of what this command looks like would be great!

Comment: Ok the command line would look something like this. usr/bin/php -q

Comment: Home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php

Comment: OR `wget http://example.com/scripts/scriptExample.php`