# How to canceled purchase after 24 hours in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies, e-commerce

How session ended after 24 hours? e.g. If someone buys products, then stock of products will decrease, but they did not confirm / pay for it, so that their purchases will be canceled and stock products will increase again.

Comment: what have you **tried yourself** so far?

Comment: I just wanna know the logic, not the source code. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: SO is not a service for free algorithm ideas.. but have you tried *regularly checking for aged out orders*?

Answer (score 0):

To use a session in php, you can use `$_SESSION` by `session_start()`
And after particular time period use `session_destroy()` to clear. But, before this update product information which are not confirmed by user. Or you can use job scheduler like :

- php cron
- phpjobscheduler

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a cron job with a script that verify the user accounts.

An example: the cron job runs every hour and call a php script that check for the dates of the user requests. If the user requested a product 24 hours ago or more and not paid for it, then the cron job script will just delete the user request and stock the product again.

Know more about cron jobs here [Executing a PHP script with a CRON Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144350/executing-a-php-script-with-a-cron-job).