# How to insert data into mysql table at a particular time using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a test in my code.For that, I need to insert data into the database table. I am able to do this. Now, I need to schedule the test to run at a particular time. For that, I need to insert data into mysql table at a particular time. How can I insert data into the mysql table a particular time automatically using php.

Comment: Cron jobs are your friend

Comment: Please share a code with us.

Comment: Thank you for user suggestions.

Comment: I got an idea to do this.

Comment: you can user cron jobs

Comment: you can use cron job to that Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144350/executing-a-php-script-with-a-cron-job